# Export details of categorised emails to Excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I found the below script online and tried to modify. I would like to check the Color Category instead of flagged emails.

So as an example, it would not check if an email is flagged and then export the details to excel, but it would export all and add a Column 6 about the Category (name) the email is marked.

Here is the code for processing the emails in Outlook

```
Sub ProcessMailFolders(ByVal objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objFlaggedMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
    Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.Folder

    For i = 1 To objCurrentFolder.Items.Count
        If objCurrentFolder.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
            'Export the information of each flagged email to Excel
            Set objMail = objCurrentFolder.Items(i)
            If objMail.IsMarkedAsTask = True And objMail.FlagStatus <> olFlagComplete Then
                Set objFlaggedMail = objMail

                With objExcelWorksheet
                    nLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & nLastRow) = objFlaggedMail.Subject
                    .Range("B" & nLastRow) = objFlaggedMail.TaskStartDate
                    .Range("C" & nLastRow) = objFlaggedMail.TaskDueDate
                    .Range("D" & nLastRow) = objFlaggedMail.SenderName
                    .Range("E" & nLastRow) = objFlaggedMail.To
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
            Call ProcessMailFolders(objSubfolder)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The code referring to Excel I was able to modify, but not with checking the categorisation instead of flagged emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the 'if' statement. Mail Items have a property called categories which returns a string.
Change:

```
If objMail.IsMarkedAsTask = True And objMail.FlagStatus <> olFlagComplete Then
```

To:

```
If objMail.Categories = ***Insert Category Name In Quotes*** Then
```

Comment: Comparing  against a single value wont' work - Categories property returns a ";" separated list of categories if more than one is set.